# Gradle Error when attempting to create apk file for my app

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I am trying to create an apk file for my app so that I can run it on my physical device and share it with other beta testers.

I am currently getting a Gradle error saying:

> could not load the compiled class for build file: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.5\android\build.gradle'from cache

I'm new to flutter / coding and don't know where to find this file, any help would be appreciated.

This is what my Gradle looks like:

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just deleting everything under ~/.gradle/caches/0.9-rc-2/scripts.
or maybe due to security software running on your machine.

Comment: okay, where do I find this ? I am very new to coding so I know how to change / manipulate the code but I don't know where everything is located.